# Flashlight/Bright Light Damaging LED/LCD screen?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, webcam, lcd, led

It is known that direct sunlight on a LED or LCD screen can cause damage.

Would a flashlight of 110 lumen shining directly on a LCD or LED screen cause damage to the screen?

Would that same 110 lumen flashlight directly shined at the webcam damage it?

Could the damage result from heating up?

Simply searching this on google shows mixed results or not specifically addressing how many lumens cause damage.

Comment: A car headlight is over 2000lumen....and it wont even put a dent on any lcd. Much less a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a fair comparison to compare sunlight with LED lights. The reason is that LED lights only give light at very narrow bands in the spectrum. The total energy that this gives is very low compared to the sun, which gives light from all across the spectrum. This is why they are efficient.

To give an idea, the [sun](https://www.newport.com/t/introduction-to-solar-radiation) gives off around **11 Watts** of energy per cm2 (square centimeter).  A [led light of 5W](https://www.amazon.ca/Wireless-Cordless-Power-Light-1500mw/dp/B075FPP68V) (~300 lumen) gives off less than **1.5 watts** per cm2. So the energy is around more than 10 times less.

The damage to LCD or webcams would be more from the **residual heat coming from infrared.** And LED don't give off any infrared. You never feel heat in front of them.

P.S. Feel free to correct my math if needed...I'm just your average repairman.

Comment: This is mainly correct but might be worth specifically mentioning that Infrared causes heating effects and items left out in direct sunlight can raise device temperatures above what they are rated for causing damage that way. At the other side of the visible spectrum ultraviolet light can cause ionization in many chemicals, plastics and dyes and is what causes colour degradation and plastics to degrade. Flashlights typically do not emit UV, except for special ones. As you mention flashlights only emit what we need to see, though heat (infrared) *is* a product of all electronics, LEDs included.

Comment: In LEDs though their efficiency is what makes them desirable, they emit *far less* heat than an incandescent bulb for a similar amount of visible light. Their main problem though is that their light emitting elements are typically much smaller and so the heat produced is more focused and so the LEDs tend to be mounted on a heat dissipating material or use a large array of smaller LEDs to spread out the thermal load. Many "high brightness" single LED torches have quite a large heatsink mounted behind the LED for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It should not. I would not do such a thing, but a flashlight is vastly less intense than sunlight. One needs safety glasses to view an eclipse. No such need for flashlights. Still, I do not recommend it just to be sure.